# Pull title and subtitle from 2 different columns in a nested tibble

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I want to use two regular character columns to create titles and subtitles for a series of figures from a nested tibble. I can get one column into the title using the .x and .y functionality. For example:

```
    library(tidyverse)

    df <- mtcars %>%
      filter(carb %in% c(1, 2, 4)) %>%
      mutate(carb = as.character(carb), gear = as.character(gear))

    df_with_plots <- df %>% 
      group_by(carb, gear) %>% 
      nest() %>% 
      mutate(plot = map(data, function(.x) { 
        .x  %>%
          ggplot() +
          geom_histogram(aes(mpg))
      }))

df_with_plots
 carb  gear    data             plot  
  <chr> <chr> <list>           <list>
1 4     4     <tibble [4 × 9]> <gg>  
2 1     4     <tibble [4 × 9]> <gg>  
3 1     3     <tibble [3 × 9]> <gg>  
4 2     3     <tibble [4 × 9]> <gg>  
5 4     3     <tibble [5 × 9]> <gg>  
6 2     4     <tibble [4 × 9]> <gg>  
7 2     5     <tibble [2 × 9]> <gg>  
8 4     5     <tibble [1 × 9]> <gg>  

    figs <- map2(df_with_plots$plot, df_with_plots$gear, ~ .x + labs(title = paste("Number of gears", .y))) 

    figs[[1]]
```

This will produce a series of figures with the  a series of figures with "Number of gears" .y in the title. How can I get both gears and carb (first two columns) in the title?

Comment: You need to use map2 inside your mutate. And your .x which is data has to be .x$col i.e. use labs in mutate after nest with map2

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I have written before and the data is also a nested data frame. I don't have a computer so I cannot create your example.

```
plots_bar <- plots_bar_data %>% 
  mutate(plots = map2(data, Source, function(.x, .y){ .x %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x= .x$n, y=.x$nn)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill= farver[2]) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=.x$nn), vjust = -.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 45, 5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 24, 2)) +
  labs(y = "Antal dage", 
       x="Antal scanninger",
       title = paste0(.y, ": Antal dage med antal scanninger")) +
      my_theme
  }))


#   for(i in 1:4){
# print(plots_bar$plots[[i]])
# }
```